# Set up SDE Raster Dataset alias layer name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, alias, raster-dataset

Is it possible to set up SDE Raster Dataset alias layer name? Like it does in feature class?

[image]

Comment: New development in enterprise geodatabase raster support ended by ArcGIS 9.3.  I haven't used rasters in the database since 10.1, and even then it was getting quirky.  If the UI won't let you do it, no you can't do it. Having a graphic of just a feature class properties page when you are asking about raster dataset properties is confusing. In the future, please  specify the ArcGIS release in use within the body of the Question.

Comment: I am using a 10.8.1 SDE Geodatabase version / SQLServer. I just can't understand why I can set up an alias name to feature class and tables in catalog, but not for raster datasets, since they are also 'tables' with blob fields...

Comment: BTW @Vince, why you don't use rasters in database? Do you prefer file system?

Comment: Raster datasets are *NOT* "also 'tables' with blob fields" -- It's a multi-table implementation. File system access to GeoTIFF has proven to be far more flexible and performant than filling a database log with binary data. Mosaic datasets are the modern raster solution.